# WPF DataGrid datacontext not recognizing edits unless ENTER is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have created a DataGrid MyDgr which I populate by setting

```
ObservableCollection<MyClass> mycollection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>(); 
//I then set values of the 'MyClass' properties, and add instances of 'MyClass' to 'mycollection'

MyDgr.DataContext = mycollection;
```

This works fine, and I can see the values in the datagrid.

The problem I have is when I use the UI to edit a cell in the datagrid , I have to purposely press Enter in order for this edit to be registered in 'mycollection'.
However, if I press Tab or if I select another cell after an edit, the previous edit does not get registered at all.

In the XAML, I have:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDgr" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
```

I am not sure if I should use something like:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DgrModelParameters" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CellEditEnding="MyDgr_OnCellEditEnding">
```

But if so, what should I put in the event handler 'MyDgr_OnCellEditEnding'?

Comment: Please add your columns declaration to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what was wrong. I am now using:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyCol" Binding="{Binding MyCol, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="80"/>
```

And everything works fine as intended.